# How does one convert DC to AC in context of playing audio?

Tags: microcontroller, analog, audio, dac, dc-ac

I'm working on a little gadget. A simple two button mini game with a simple oled i2c display. I wanted to add sound and a bit of music. Nothing too fancy, mainly drums using white noise and two or three square and sawtooth wave voices for melodies and rhythm.

From what I understand I need a DAC which can be used to produce various levels of DC voltage and then offset it to produce an AC signal for speakers / headphones. I've seen schematics where this was done with nothing more than a capacitor but the logic eludes me. Would any kind folks help me out with understanding how one goes from DC (say from a 3.3c 8bit or 16bit DAC) to ac that is audio speaker friendly?

Comment: What you're asking for is not converting DC to AC, it's removing a DC offset from a signal. That might help you find some resources.

Comment: Oh I see. Something new I've learned. Should I edit the comment to clarify that?

Comment: If you use a bunch of unipolar voltages (what you are calling DC) to make a sine-wave, it will be a sine-wave offset to entirely be unipolar. What speakers and headphones want is a sine-wave with no offset such that it is centered around zero and is bipolar (goes both positive and negative). So you want to remove offset. Mathematically going both ways is adding some offset, but physically there is a difference because removing DC offset is easier than adding DC offset. You just use a capacitor, in this case a so called DC-blocking capacitor. If that's what you don't get, dig into how caps work

Comment: That explains why I could not find anything related when looking for DC to AC conversion as a search query. Thank you very much for clarifying that.

I assume that there's a formula to calculating the capacitance based on the DAC output voltage?

Comment: The capacitor removes DC bias so only AC is left. So in your terms it converts DC to AC. How large voltage is has nothing to do with capacitance, just your frequencies and speaker impedance. Unless you have an amplifier.

Comment: It's more about the frequency involved than the voltage. DC = 0Hz. Audio = some range of non-zero Hz. And the size of the cap will reflect how easily certain frequencies are allowed to pass through unimpeded. It takes a larger and larger cap to pass lower and lower frequencies. It would take an infinite capacitor to pass DC and those don't exist. So all capacitors block DC, and other lower non-zero frequencies pass through more or less easily depending on how big it is.

Comment: So the value of the capacitor determines the cutoff frequency, past which the signal simply cannot pass because the capacitor is storing and releasing current thus smoothing out anything past that frequency?

Comment: RC filters are not on-off devices, but linear. They attenuate with a slope of 20 dB per decade.

Comment: The capacitor acts as a high-pass filter in this case, not a low-pass one; it attenuates low frequencies and lets high ones through unimpeded. That's what you want, because you want to block DC (the lowest frequency, 0 Hz) while allowing through audio frequencies (about 20 Hz to 20 kHz). The capacitor will also, in theory, allow through anything of a higher frequency too.

Comment: I see. That makes perfect sense. DC or direct current is essentially AC with a alternating frequency of Zero. I'm sure I'm butchering this analogy with that sort of an explanation but this is what I'm extrapolating from your elaboration here.

Comment: @user2175010 Are you expecting to just provide *both* a built-in speaker and also a jack for headphones? Also, speakers semi-traditionally are about \$8\:\Omega\$ in overall impedance. But can be found with smaller and larger values. Headphones are more commonly in the area of \$32\:\Omega\$ or more (expensive \$600\:\Omega\$ and higher can be bought.) Another aspect of headphones is that they don't require anywhere near the power output that a typical speaker does. So you really need to consider and let us know the scope of what you want to achieve, just on this single aspect, let alone more.

Comment: @user2175010 I'd hate to drill-down on your single question of DC and AC, only to fail completely on what you are really wanting to achieve. These things are usually well-specified at the outset (what the "business" end requires in terms of user functionality) and the designers then figure out what behavioral blocks make sense to get there. And then each block is worked out, with how they connect/communicate between each other using well-understood mechanisms, and that results in each block having its own well-specified inputs and outputs within the overall system. Then each block is done.

Comment: @user2175010 If a headphone jack is sufficient, then the power requirements go *way down* and become quite easy to do (and cheap.) But if you need a speaker in open air that will be heard, then the power requirement may go *way up* and require a different path. You could also just decide to produce a signal compatible with the many amplifier stages available everywhere that supply both speakers and headphone jacks for you, with you supplying an output that is designed to meet their input requirements (which are broadly standardized.) Lots of ways to go.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to add sound and a bit of music ... the simplest way.

If I understand correctly, you want to make "sound" as simply as possible.
Just use the way digital amplifiers using PWM work.
To do this, use two equal resistors to define a voltage midpoint on a GPIO output with the possibility of Tri-state, coupling to the load (high input impedance loudspeaker or piezo, transformer could be used) by a capacitor.
Then apply the sequence of 0 or 1 or Z as desired to restore a sound.
(NB: to create it, one can use the sequence obtained by inputting the original signal wanted through a comparator - either v=0 or Vcc/2).
NB: variations are possible.

Answer (score 1):

A rapidly varying DC signal is indistinguishable from an AC signal with a DC offset (equal to the average voltage) applied.

A capacitor in series with the speaker will block DC, and allow AC through.  The impedance of a capacitor is

> X = 1 / 2πfC

where C is the capacitance, and f the frequency.  DC has a frequency of 0Hz, so the impedance is infinite.

If you haven't got a DAC, then use PWM on a digital pin instead - see the answer by Antonio51.